# RSSI Smoothing using LQI in Android

Tags: android, bluetooth, kalman-filter, rssi, eddystone

I am making an application that centers around an easily readable RSSI value. Currently the RSSI jumps around too much for my use case (i.e. being able to tell if the signal is getting stronger or weaker as I walk around) I have built a sample application using Kalman filters, but would also like to test the Improved Fusion Filter found in section 3.6 of this paper https://journals.sagepub.com/doi/full/10.1155/2015/195297.

Unfortunately this requires LQI measurements from the beacon. I believe this is sent in byte offset 16 of the eddystone encrypted TLM frame but I am not sure. Is there another way to calculate or read LQI on android?

Answer (score 0):

From your linked paper:

> Given that LQI is a superior metric, it should not be forgotten that **it is only made available by 802.15.4 compliant devices**. It therefore makes sense to use RSSI as much as possible.

No where in the current [Android Compatibility Definition Document for Android 10 - Bluetooth section](https://source.android.com/compatibility/10/android-10-cdd#7_4_3_bluetooth) does it state compatibility with that standard. If any Android device does so, it would be have to be specifically setup by manufacturer.

Answer (score 0):

Android SDKs provide no APIs to access a LQI measurement from the Bluetooth interface.

In general RSSI smoothing can improve noise on the measurement, but all algorithms have the drawback of adding lag to the measurement at some times.

The simplest running average algorithm using a 20 second interval, for example, provides good results at reception rates of 1Hz but is not an ideal choice  if the transmitter and receiver are in motion.  Such an algorithm essentially tells you the signal strength of the target 10 seconds ago when relative motion is in a straight line.

Other algorithms can improve this trade-off a bit, but the improvements are subtle and often difficult to measure.  Don't expect any alrforithms to provide a magic bullet.